# Facebook OG tags not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jsp, facebook-graph-api

I have this in my base jsp. This is included in all pages

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

I'm trying to replace the values of this meta tags using jquery/js and I have this code.

```
$("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", ogTitle);
$("meta[property='og\\:description']").attr("content", ogDescription);
$("meta[property='og\\:image']").attr("content", ogImage);
$("meta[property='og\\:url']").attr("content", link.href);
$("meta[property='fb\\:app_id']").attr("content", appId);
```

When I debug it, it shows the right details and it gets the right values.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<meta property="og:url" content="my_app_url">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

Etc.. it gets the right values but when I try to share it. it only shows my url in Facebook. I tried using this. [Facebook dev tools debug sharing](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

and it shows this errors :

"The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

"Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers."

"The 'og:type' property is required, but not present."

"The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

"The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog."

It's weird to see this errors because I know that I already have the values. Any idea?

I really can't see or maybe understand where the answer is from the other, is it a problem when you are using a url like, 194.23.21.49/ProjectName/Project??? Is this a new scenario or this doesn't affect any? I really can't understand the problem since I'm seeing the right values in html, but doesn't translate to the facebook share.

Comment: Hi @CBroe see edit please need clarifications..

Comment: Give an example URL where we can have a look at the problem.

Comment: my url looks like this @CBroe http://192.168.1.1:8080/SiteName unfortunately I cannot give the exact url. :( but it looks like that

Comment: Your URL needs to be reachable from the outside by Facebook's servers - which is of course not the case when you use a local IP address.

Comment: OMG. Thank you.. Can you put this as an answer so i can mark it as answered